# How to make Cordova/IONIC app to work well with Browser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

We have a mobile app that is built on cordova/ionic/Angular4 but now we are in need of companion desktop app(we did not see that coming). We tried to render the app as is(with minor CSS tweaks) but they are not looking good and effort is more to make changes in every component

Certainly we do not want to maintain two code bases one for mobile and desktop. Can anyone educate me what are the options?

Comment: What exactly does not look good? Is it the layout?

Comment: Alignment on wider screen , layout, fonts etc. I will try to get the screen shot of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [Ionic's grid system](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/). It comes with elements and predefined attributes (similar to Bootstrap) to build custom, responsive layouts.
Here's a great tutorial on how to build layouts that scale from mobile to desktop: https://blog.ionicframework.com/build-awesome-desktop-apps-with-ionics-new-responsive-grid/

Comment: Sure. we wil take a look

Comment: it is promising. we will give a try